# Saving animated render from compositor (with denoise)

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, denoise, saving

So basically I'd like to denoise an animation I did, and I know the settings to achieve denoise on the compositor, but it only really shows me one frame of it. When I try to save the render result, it only offers me the option of saving as a PNG as opposed to a video format. How do I go about saving the whole video, but denoised? Do I have to re-render the whole thing?

Note: I composited only after I finished rendering the whole animation

Comment: The rendered frames not stored in Blender, you have to save them while rendering. Use the File Output node in the Compositor. Save all frame in a folder then create an image sequence in the Video Sequence Editor, and render it as a video file.